# c# ListView populated with Current Processes Informations: PID/Process Name/Path error when not compiled for x64

Tags: c#, exception, process, path, windows-7-x64

I'm running a Windows 7 x64 machine when I do not compile for x64 I get an exception and my ListView just get populated with the first two non x64 processes.

That is I cannot access MainModule Property of a 64 bit process to get it's full path.

```
foreach(Process p in listaProcessi) 
{
    tempItem = new ListViewItem(p.Id.ToString());
    tempItem.SubItems.Add(p.ProcessName);
    tempItem.SubItems.Add(p.MainModule.FileName);
    processiListView.Items.Add(tempItem);
}
```

I still can make it work compiling for x64 but suppose I want to compile just for x86, how do I avoid getting the excpetion ?

1) **Is there any other way to discover those processes path ?**

2) I could write a line like "You cannot get x64 Process path from x86 App", but still I don't have to run into the exception. How do I prevent this ? Can I check the process for a particular info so I can replace the text and avoid accessing MainModule ?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the exception stack trace and details? Try to build for AnyCPU, not x86 and not x64... how does it work?

Comment: Are you getting the "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Unable to enumerate the process modules"? This is usually true for processes running under "System" credentials irrespective of x86 and x64.

Comment: By default it Runs an Active Debug (Config) Platform: Active(x86)
Platform target: x86

This generates:
Exception:Thrown: "A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process." (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
A System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown: "A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process."
By changing to Platform target: x64 or AnyCPU I don't get any exception.

So selecting AnyCPU should be fine because If I run it on my System it will run as x64 and so it can access x64 Modules if run on x86 machine should work because there is no x64 process.

Comment: Anyway are there any other methods to get a process file path ? Just for curiosity. :)

Comment: You need to use the WMI. Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9738145/385995).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.

So it must be compiled for AnyCpu to be fully working in both x86 and x64 environments.