# Getting the icon associated with a 64 bit process in c#?

Tags: c#, process, icons

I'm trying to list all my processes with their respective icons, and i'm getting the icon like this:

```
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(process.MainModule.FileName);
```

But i get this error "A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process."

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, then you need to compile your application for AnyCPU Platform

I assume that the message is displayed because you compile you application for x86 and thus, the emitted code is 32bit code. The message clearly says that a 32bit app cannot access a 64bit module.

If you compile with AnyCPU then your code will be executed as 64bit code on 64bit Operating Systems.
This should allow to access the 64bit processes as well the 32bit processes.

Comment: I guess i'm compiling for AnyCPU (http://i.imgur.com/or3bHmy.png), that's why it confuses me.

Comment: Check also in the DEBUG menu the settings under Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread , it may helps you

[How to avoid a Win32 exception when accessing Process.MainModule.FileName in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501771/how-to-avoid-a-win32-exception-when-accessing-process-mainmodule-filename-in-c/)