# Win32Exception (0x80004005) When Looping Through Process Modules

Tags: c#

Yesterday this exception started to occurr and I have no idea why it is happening. If I change `p[0]` to `p[1]` it stops the error, but it doesn't get client.dll. [Screenshot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAJJn.png)

```
            Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(Offsets.pro);

             if (p.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (ProcessModule m in p[0].Modules)
                {
                    if (m.ModuleName == "client.dll")
                    {
                        Offsets.bClient = (int)m.BaseAddress;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its good to put the error message in the question text, even if you already have it in the title.

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137(v=vs.85).aspx), 0x80004005 is an E_FAIL (Unspecified failure).  Good luck.

Comment: what do i do then? any tips?

Comment: possibly http://stackoverflow.com/a/9502058/74015

Comment: the thing is is didnt changed anything i got it that i cant access mainmodule 0 but how did i was doing it before and now i cant i dont understand.

Comment: ok i got it resolved /close please

Comment: Hi Franz. What was the solution? You can post the answer to your own question if you figured it out. It might be helpful to anyone running into the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it restarting my pc apparently the vs was bugged XD.