# Process.MainModule enumeration fails when ran as service

Tags: c#, service, process

I'm writing a service in which I need to get a filename of process curently being active.

I have code similar to that below (I have stripped out sanity checks)

```
Process currentProcess = GetActiveProcess();
ProcessModule currentModule = currentProcess.MainModule;
string FileName = currentModule.FileName.ToLower();
```

And it works like a charm when I compile it and run as a winforms application.

But when I run the exact same code as a service (no matter if I run service as a LocalSystem user or admin user same that runs code as application) it throws exception at second line:

> Unable to enumerate the process modules

I've already tried to:

- add:

  ```
  [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
  [HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, SharedState = true, Synchronization = true, ExternalProcessMgmt = true, SelfAffectingProcessMgmt = true)]
  [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
  class WindowsService : ServiceBase
  ```
- set service to start as an admin user
- add to app.manifest:

  ```
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  ```

None of this worked. 
What do I have to do to get MainModule?

Comment: What specific exception type do you get? Have you looked at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: Yes, I do. Exception is Win32Exception but it does not make sense to me because I've checked it on Windows XP 32bit and Windows 7 32bit.

Comment: I've checked other method of getting filename from Process and result is the same, error slighty different - Access denied. Even if service is running with admin credintentials.
So it's pretty sure that being a service is a reason why there is no access to Process.MainModule.

Answer (score 0):

Ever since Vista, services are barred from interacting with teh Desktop. Afaik a measure to make certain they would not circumvent the UAC.

And not having access to the Desktop (not an [interactive session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) can cause issues with just about anything, especially the old CoM Classes for Office File handling.

So that is the best thing I can give you, if you do not give us what is happening/not happening (in particular the error message). But the WinForms/Service difference makes this the likely cause.

Comment: I tried it on Windows 7 but also on Windows XP and results are the same, so it rather not because of UAC.
But when I check in service properties that it may interact with desktop my service crashes at startup

Comment: This seems to be a solution to a simialr case. Maybe it help you further? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502058/3346583

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. My app is 32bit in 32bit OS, and it's working ok when I run it as a application, problem starts when I run it as a service.

Comment: One of hte first hings this solution doe is explain how that is a error message from the Windows Itself (outside .NET Code) and how you need the precise information (Native Code Error), because otherwise it is guesswork for days.