# How to find the running console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I can find if the target app is currently running or not by this code. But I want to also find out the execution path of that application. But I can't see a way to do it. Please tell me how can I find it execution path?

```
static public bool IsProcessRunning(string name)
{
    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) 
    {
        if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/c-how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process) thread C#: How to get the full path of running process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process instance and use the MainModule Property to get the location.

Something like this

```
static public bool IsProcessRunning(string name)
{
   foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) 
   {
       if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
          {
            Console.WriteLine(clsProcess.MainModule.FileName);
            return true;
           }
         }
         return false;
}
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.

Comment: check this out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501771/how-to-avoid-a-win32-exception-when-accessing-process-mainmodule-filename-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet.

```
 var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); // Or whatever method you are using
 string fullPath = process.MainModule.FileName;
```

**Update**

```
public string GetProcessPath(string name)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(name);

    if (processes.Length > 0)
    {
        return processes[0].MainModule.FileName;
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find out another application's execution path, not the current app's execution path.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.

Comment: if your process is unmanaged code, so it cannot return a .NET object as MainModule

Comment: You can also try to run your application as any cpu

Answer (score 0):

You could get the path by.

```
var executionPath = clsProcess.MainModule.FileName
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.

Answer (score 0):

try the MainModule property

```
clsProcess.MainModule.FileName
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.

Comment: @masiboo compile it as 64 bit then...

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ProcessModule.FileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Property:

```
var runningDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(process.MainModule.FileName);
```

Comment: I get exceptions as: Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.