# Access denied when i try to kill process with specific location that run as admin C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem of killing an exe with specific location that runs as administrator. Here is the code i use:

```
 const string PROCESSNAME = "test";
 string targetProcessPath = @Path.Combine(myFolder, "test.exe");
 Process[] collectionOfProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(PROCESSNAME);
 if (collectionOfProcess.Length >= 1)
 {
      Process process = collectionOfProcess[0];
      string processPath = process.MainModule.FileName;
      if (processPath == targetProcessPath)
           process.Kill();
}
```

The problem is it works fine when i run test.exe normally but "access denied" when i run it as administrator. I have also tried to run my program as administrator but it still throws the "access denied" exception. Any help on how to achieve that?

Comment: Did you check if this is OK: `processPath == targetProcessPath`  ?

Comment: Maybe this is a better way to do that check:  `String.Compare(processPath,targetProcessPath,true)==0`

Comment: @Luuk thanks for your reply but the code you recommended still throws access denied. Only when i run the test.exe as administrator though (my program also run as administrator).

Comment: Conclusion, you are not allowed to access `process.MainModule.FileName` of the process which is running under administrator, while you yourself is not an administrator.  (But `process.Kill()` still works, but then you will not know if you killed the right process.....)

Comment: It does kill the right process, if i run two "test.exe" one is right folder and second is from another it will only kill the first one.

Comment: see this post for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501771/how-to-avoid-a-win32-exception-when-accessing-process-mainmodule-filename-in-c

Comment: Well yeah like you said cant access process.MainModule.FileName despite running my program as administrator, that is why im asking if i have a way to achieve that.