# How to kill all processes running within a folder and its subfolders? (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What's the easiest method to killing all apps running under a folder and all of its subfolders using WinForms?

I would try killing individual processes but that would be less efficient and if more get added to that folder then I'd have to update my code every time.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have the code to straight up kill a program, but I need to get a piece of code that will go through a folder and all of its subfolders and find every file ending with .exe and add it to an array, I can do the rest myself.

Comment: Please show what you have. Why do you need to read the files in the folder, why not just search through running processes for ones which match the path?

Comment: Now that I think about it, that would probably work better. I just need to make sure it'd work for everything in any subfolders too. Here's my code to kill an app:

            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }

Answer (score 0):

I would also kill processes via process name to ensure a given process is terminated on various paths.
However you can do something like:

```
string processPath = @"c:\blablabla";

Process[] currentProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in currentProcesses)
{
    if (process.MainModule != null &&
        process.MainModule.FileName == processPath)
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MainModule` property to get the path for every process, then just check if it starts with your path.

Don't forget to dispose the process objects when done.

```cs
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
try
{
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (process.MainModule?.FileName?.StartsWith(yourPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false)
                process.Kill();
        }
        catch
        { //
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    foreach (var process in processes)
        process.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this, but I'm getting the error "Unable to enumerate the process modules.", do you know what that is? I could totally be doing something stupid

Comment: Probably need to be admin. What is the name of the process causing this issue, is it a system process and which user is it running under?

Comment: It isn't a system process, but it might be running under system. I tried running it as administrator to no avail.

Comment: @Dwayne_The_Rock_Johnson Try compiling for x64 CPU. can you give more info about the exception, what is the exception type, and error number if it's Win32? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501771/how-to-avoid-a-win32-exception-when-accessing-process-mainmodule-filename-in-c

Comment: I am compiling for X64, and when in debug mode it points to 
"if (process.MainModule?.FileName?.StartsWith("C:\\Program Files", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false)"

With this exeption: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Unable to enumerate the process modules.'

Comment: Also do note that I can kill the processes in task manager if I try

Comment: The error code is -2147467259

Comment: Not the HResult, the `NativeErrorCode` property

Comment: Sorry for the delay, anyway, that is the NativeErrorCode.